# Help me solve this definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^c\frac{t^n}{x-t}dt$$Is there any standard formula for this?

n can be real; I need for a specific case of n=0.5. Thanks!

Comment: Sub $t=x+y$.  Use the binomial theorem.

Comment: So will dt=dy then?

Comment: also for binomial theorem n should be an integer , what if n=1/2?

Answer (score 2):

If $n$ is a whole number, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\dfrac{t^n}{x-t}&=&\dfrac{t^n-x^n}{x-t}+\dfrac{x^n}{x-t}=t^{n-1}+xt^{n-2}+\ldots+x^{n-2}t+x^{n-1}-x^n\cdot\dfrac{1}{t-x}\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{n-1-k}t^k-x^n\cdot\dfrac{1}{t-x},
\end{eqnarray}
it follows that
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^c\dfrac{t^n}{x-t}\,dt&=&\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{n-1-k}\int_0^c t^k\,dt-x^n\cdot\int_0^c\dfrac{1}{t-x}\,dt=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{n-1-k}\dfrac{t^{k+1}}{k+1}\Big|_{t=0}^{t=c}-x^n\cdot\ln|t-x|\Big|_{t=0}^{t=c}\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{c^{k+1}}{k+1}x^{n-1-k}-x^n[\ln|x-c|-\ln|x|]
\end{eqnarray}

---

If $n=0.5$, set $t=u^2$, so that
$$
I(c,x)\int_0^c\dfrac{t^{0.5}}{x-t}\,dt=\int_0^{\sqrt{c}}\dfrac{u}{x-u^2}\,du
$$
Clearly
$$
I(c,0)=-\int_0^{\sqrt{c}}\dfrac{1}{u}\,du=-\ln\sqrt{c}=-\dfrac12\ln c.
$$
If $x\ne0$, then
$$
I(c,x)=-\int_0^{\sqrt{c}}\dfrac{u}{u^2-x}\,du=-\dfrac12\ln|u^2-x|\Big|_{u=0}^{u=\sqrt{c}}=-\frac12\left(\ln|x-c|-\ln|x|\right)
$$

Comment: Is this true for a fractional n?

Comment: If we use your method for sa n=1, the first term in the summation is +c, where as the actual answer is -c.

Comment: ahh, I got it, when you use a^n-b^n expansion, you will have (a-b) in the numerator, but we have (b-a) in the denominator, so there will be negative sign in front of the series expansion. You can edit that. Thanks a lot!